# Vue.js: Assigning computed result to data property at created or mounted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to do the following?

```
export default {
  props: ['parentArray'],
  data () {
    return {
      computedArray: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedResult: function () {
    var flags = []
    var output = []
    var l = this.parentArray.length
    var i
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (flags[this.parentArray[i].myitem]) continue
        flags[this.parentArray[i].myitem] = true
        var firstfilter = this.parentArray[i].myitem.replace('something', '')
        output.push(firstfilter)
      }
    return output
   }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.computedArray = this.computedResult
  }
```

When I try, the structure of my array makes it to the data element, but none of the data (at least not in the vue dev-tools. The computed array properly shows up in computed)

Comment: I don't see any problems with this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/v1qh7zm3/.
Try clicking Refresh in the dev tools if you don't see the data.

Comment: And yet when I try this in a vue app locally, the array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, the unexpected result was because of something outside the logic of the particular question. In my case, my `parentArray` was coming from an axios call, which is async, which meant that it did not arrive until AFTER the component was mounted, and hence my empty array. Adding a check for loaded data (by setting data item `loaded` to `false`, then setting it to `true` in my axios response and finally adding `v-if="loaded"` to my component made it work as expected.

So the answer to the question above is YES, this is possible (BUT make sure your parent prop data is available before mounting).